# Problem with a jQuery script in the head tag

Tags: jquery, html

I declared some `<p>` elements inside `body`. In the head tag, I wrote some jQuery code inside `<script>` tag, but my document is not working while output.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Untitled Document</title>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $("p").click(function(){
        $(this).hide();
      })    
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <h2>javascript click function: click the p elements to hide it</h2>
  <p>hii click me to disappear</p>
  <p>hii click me too</p>
  <p>hii once again</p>

  <script src="jquery.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you have some errors in [console](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-do-i-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers)?

Comment: Do you have JQuery.js on your server, in the same directory as your html?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "not working"?

Answer (score 1):

if you look console, you will certainly see why it doesnt work.

> Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

so, add  `<script src="jquery.js"></script>` before your script.

Comment: The jQuery lib is called at the end of the file... And the script in inside a document ready handler... Looks good to me.

Comment: Document ready is a jQuery method not js. So it won't run if it is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

```html
    <!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
         <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function(){
       $("p").click(function(){
        $(this).hide();
    })  
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<h2>javascript click function: click the p elements 
  to hide it</h2>
<p>hii click me to disappear</p>
<p>hii click me too</p>
<p>hii once again</p>


 <script src="jquery.js"></script>
 </body>
 </html>
```

just add: `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>` inside head tag

Comment: The jQuery lib is called at the end of the file... And the script in inside a document ready handler... Looks good to me.